# How to transfer SQLite DB from handheld to wearable?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, wear-os

I have an app with 2 modules: 1 for an hanheld and the other one is for a wearable.
I have the DB on my handheld module and I need to copy it somehow to the wearable. My DB is really small, it contains only strings so it shouldn't be a problem to copy it.

At first I tried to use a shared DB for both modules (with a singelton class) but without luck, each module saw a different DB no matter what I did.
My second attempt was to send it through the data layer from the handheld to the wearable but I`m not exactly sure how to do it and in addition I saw that I need to export my DB to a file each time and it seems a bit too complicated.

Please try to help me figure out what is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Handheld:**

1. select all rows from the `table` and put them into `DataMap` object
2. send the `DataMap` object using `DataApi`

**Wearable:**

1. `receive the DataMap object using DataApi`
2. `delete all rows from the table and insert the received.`

Comment: Can you please tell me how to put all the rows in a data map object and how to extract it? Is there a single command for selecting all rows or should I go one by one with the cursor and it to an array? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I don't know a convenient way to select all rows. I use Cursor -> ArrayList -> DataMap. It's not elegant, but works.